# Problem With INDEX MATCH Function For Column In Two Tabs Using Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match, spreadsheet

I am having a problem using the INDEX MATCH function in Excel to match the names of companies in two separate tabs. Each tab is named for an ETF (XBI, IBB). The companies listed in each tab are identified by the column Name. I created a third tab to pull the companies' names (and ticker symbols) from both tabs to match what companies are held by both ETFs.

The formula I used is as follows:

=INDEX(XBI[Name],MATCH([@[Name]],XBB[Name],0)

I'm not sure if I noted the array/reference cell correctly and would welcome some help as to what I did wrong with my formula above. I've included a picture for everyone's review.

Thanks in advance for looking at my problem, appreciate it.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQN7G.jpg)

Comment: as it is you need one last parenthesis (close)... =INDEX( XBI[Name], MATCH( [@[Name]], XBB[Name], 0 ) )

Comment: Are both lists the same length?

Comment: @ Solar Mike: Each list of names is a different length (XBI - 191, IBB - 272). Hope that helps.